# Angular Material Grid List not fitting height of content

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, grid

Im building a grid with material and inside have a list of items.
Grid is responsive.

When trying to stretch for smaller screens the content of each column is not diplayed at all but has a fixed height.

[image]

[image]

Demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid-7mf3kr?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.css,app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.ts,app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.html,app%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html

Comment: grid rows usually have a fixed height, rowHeight directive is used to do this, does the row height need to be dynamic?

Comment: @Mr.Stash each row have different items. When screen size is small they go vertical and have different heights as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `<mat-grid-list>` that based on grid system so **there is no way Angular Material Grid List can fit height of content**.

You can use [`display: flex` with div](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of `<mat-grid-list>` component and define [the @media query when screen's width reaches 400px](https://linuxhint.com/min-width-max-width-media-queries/#4) to set 1 item per row instead of 3.